# Change table columns order using drag drop Angular 8

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-material, angular8, typescript3.0

I am creating an application with:
`Angular CLI: 8.3.23`
`Node: 10.15.0`
`typescript: 3.5.3` and I need to make the table columns re-order able using drag drop. Something like this https://sindu12jun.github.io/table-dragger but I have tried multiple things like it but nothing is working. 
I tried to use some jquery plugins as well but that doesn't work either. I used this https://akottr.github.io/dragtable/ jQuery plugin but no luck.
This can be done using `<mat-table>` but due to some other requirements I don't want to use material table.

**If anyone have any idea, please let me know. Thanks**

Comment: 1. jQuery is never the answer to an Angular problem. 2. There are several draggable libraries for Angular. Try starting with the most popular ones with good documentation.

Comment: There are libraries for it but not for tables, I tried the ones available but those are not working then I thought to try jQuery instead.
Like this: https://github.com/sindu12jun/table-dragger/issues/42
If you know any libraries for Angular, can you please share ? @kurt

Comment: I'm surprised that all of the available Angular libraries don't support dragging table rows. That's a primary use case. I haven't done any drag and drop, so don't have specific advice I'm afraid.

Comment: I want to drag table columns, Yeah the once available are not working the current Angular and Typescript versions I have.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I suspect that will be harder to find as a built in feature.

Comment: You could make just your header row sortable, and then rebuild your table model on a table header being dropped.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I have make something custom like that.

Comment: i think use should dragula

Comment: @Abinash It doesn't work with default table tag, If I use it I can't keep the other functionalities I have implemented on table.

Comment: @siddharth shah I don't think they have anything for table: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula

Comment: I think that the best to drag is use the DragDropModule from @angular/ckd/drag-drop. (it's not necesary import all the material-angular). you can see an example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-tftm9d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo I was able to accomplish it by taking reference from the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it finally, check the link:
[Angular material table column dragger](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3nrvp)